# Is there a way to generate the Ruby code to instantiate an object I have a reference to?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, it would be really nice if I could generate a string that would be used to instantiate an object that I have a reference to. For example:

```
> person    
=> #<MyCrazyClass id: 231, first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Smith", age: 38, salary: #<BigDecimal:7fab6371a0f0,'0.125E6',9(18)>>
> generate_instantiation_string person
=> "MyCrazyClass.new(id: 231, first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Smith", age: 38, salary: BigDecimal.new("125000"))"
```

It would be really nice if it could generate the code to instantiate all of the objects child relationships for me too.

I know I could probably write something like this myself, but I just wanted to know if there is a gem already available to save me from having to figure out all the deep nesting and object reference stuff.

--Update--

Why would I want this? I usually find myself wanting to do this when I'm looking at some data in production and I want to quickly replicate it in a test environment, or use it to create seed scripts. Serializing it would work, but it isn't ideal. Ideally, I'd just like a string version so that I can manipulate one or two parts of it manually or through scripts.

Comment: What is the goal? Dump the db into a seed file and seed back later?

Comment: If you use rails: [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump)

Comment: you can do Marshal:dump/load as binary or Json / Yaml for strings for serialization

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with the serialized string not being human-readable (it will be in binary):

```
m = MyCrazyClass.new(id: 231, first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Smith", age: 38, salary: BigDecimal.new("125000"))
m.get_first_name()  # returns Joe

serialized = Marshal::dump(m)
obj = Marshal::load(serialized)
obj.get_first_name()  # returns Joe
```

Comment: I thought about that. I usually find myself wanting to do this when I'm looking at some data in production and I want to quickly replicate it in a test environment, or use it to create seed scripts. Serializing it would work, but it isn't ideal. Ideally, I'd just like a string version so that I can manipulate one or two parts of it manually or through scripts.

Comment: I guess it's a trade-off of ease-of-use vs functionality. Note that the binary form still has easily recognizable data strings so you should still be able to make some trivial edits

Answer (score 0):

If your need to populate db for testing - try [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

Comment: I do use FactoryGirl for testing. But, I usually find myself wanting to do this when I'm looking at some data in production and I want to quickly replicate it in a test environment, or use it to create seed scripts.